# How to call a "non-strict" monoidal category?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, monoidal-categories

A [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) is a category $\mathsf{C}$ equipped with a bifunctor $\otimes : \mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{C}$, a unit object, an associator, and right and left unitors satisfying a bunch of conditions. A *strict* monoidal category is one in which the associators and unitors are identities, basically $X \otimes (Y \otimes Z)$ is *equal* to $(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$, instead of being naturally isomorphic to it.

In some contexts, it's necessary to emphasize that a monoidal category is not strict, i.e. there really is a nontrivial associator (and unitors and so on). So far I've been calling these monoidal category "non-strict". I don't really like this terminology though, because it suggests that "strict" is the default. Is there another accepted terminology for a "non-strict" monoidal category?

Comment: If I had to give a name I guess I would say "lax monoidal category" (but that's just my suggestion, I don't think I've seen that anywhere). But I think it's like the fact that there is no name for a ring that is not a field, or for a topological space that is not metrizable (etc...). Quite often only the stronger properties have name.

Comment: @CaptainLama I don't think I would be comfortable with "lax", for me it would be something where the associator is not even an isomorphism (and so there would be "lax" and "colax" monoidal categories depending on its direction). Well it's certainly possible that there's no accepted name for this, yes...

Comment: I would probably state, when I introduced the term "monoidal", that "non-strict" may be added for emphasis upon occasion.  In shorter work, I'd probably just write "(non-strict) monoidal", or if I really wanted to emphasize it and it's not possible to be strict monoidal, then I'd say "properly non-strict monoidal" which is admittedly clumsy.  Your use of the word "non-strict" seems completely reasonable to me, and if *you* aren't already aware of the alternative terminology, your readers probably won't be either.

Comment: As every monoidal category is strictifiable, those contexts you are talking about are [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence#terminology). So, as for any evil notion, one has to get the attention of the reader that intuitively think up to equivalence: I would loudly insist by writting something like "**non necessarily strict** monodial category".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In fact, such a concept exists, but for some reason it is called a skew monoidal category.